# TFS 2012 to support Test Controller 2010

Tags: automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

We are having trouble running automated tests after updating TFS 2010 to TFS 2012.
We are using MTM 2010/2012 to run the tests. (Both have the same issues)

The critical error we encountered is: "TFS had detected that the following test controller is offline: *TestControllerServerAddress*"

Test Controller server is online and properly configured. The test service is also running.

I have been searching for solutions but didn’t find anything helpful. I do know that we can update the TFS with the 2nd update to support **BUILD Controller 2010**, but nothing said about the **TEST Controller 2010**.

Thanks for the help.

Mark.

EDIT:

I've just upgraded the Test controller to 2012. solved the problem..

Comment: Did you install the [Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)?
Why not just upgrade the test controllers to 2012

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not attempting to upgrade all the technologies at once? A while ago I attempted to upgrade to 2012 while keeping as much of my 2010 setup in place and there were so many problems I had to roll-back. Consider upgrading your controllers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use TFS2012 you need to have the Test Controller upgraded to 2012 so that it is able to grab your Test Cases. There are many issues (many of which I have personally faced) in upgrading TFS2010 to TFS2012 without upgrading the surrounding technologies. One other issue you may face is any Test Case with Rich Text formatting (made in MTM11 or MTM10 with patch) will be shown with HTML tags in any MTM10 installs, this is fixable but further points out the benefit of not relying on patches.